# Move a certain distance, turn, then move (Odometry topic)

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, nav-msgs, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, I am able to have my robot move forward for a certain distance, turn right by a certain degree, then move forward again. However, it is extremely inaccurate as highlighted in ahendrix's answer here "http://answers.ros.org/question/204973/robot-pose-slightly-off-when-publishing-to-cmd_vel/".

I want to re-make this program by using the odometry topic. This is the current code that I have, I am currently working on the TurtleBot 2.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

ros::init(argc, argv, "move_pub");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher movement_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("mobile_base/commands/velocity",1); //for sensors the value after , should be higher to get a more accurate result (queued)
ros::Rate rate(10); //the larger the value, the "smoother" , try value of 1 to see "jerk" movement

//move forward
ros::Time start = ros::Time::now();
while(ros::Time::now() - start < ros::Duration(5.0))
{
    geometry_msgs::Twist move;
    //velocity controls
    move.linear.x = 0.1; //speed value m/s
    move.angular.z = 0;
    movement_pub.publish(move);

    ros::spinOnce();
    rate.sleep();
}
//turn right
ros::Time start_turn = ros::Time::now();
while(ros::Time::now() - start_turn < ros::Duration(4.0))
{
    geometry_msgs::Twist move;
    //velocity controls
    move.linear.x = 0; //speed value m/s
    move.angular.z = -2.25;
    movement_pub.publish(move);

    ros::spinOnce();
    rate.sleep();
}
//move forward again
ros::Time start2 = ros::Time::now();
while(ros::Time::now() - start2 < ros::Duration(5.0))
{
    geometry_msgs::Twist move;
    //velocity controls
    move.linear.x = 0.1; //speed value m/s
    move.angular.z = 0;
    movement_pub.publish(move);

    ros::spinOnce();
    rate.sleep();
}

return 0;
}
```

How should I go about replicating this program using the odometry topic?

I am a beginner at ROS, all of your help will be greatly appreciated. I am currently on my school holidays and I am feeling great joy learning something new :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205132/move-a-certain-distance,-turn,-then-move-(odometry-topic)/) by [dylankc](https://answers.ros.org/users/21875/dylankc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-03-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dylankc](https://answers.ros.org/users/21875/dylankc/) on 2015-03-16**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/205134/odometry-based-out-and-back-script-py-to-c/

I was able to find a python script in a library book that achieves this. However, I dont know how to replicate as a ROS C++ node, I posted it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I started from your code and did some changes in order to use an Odometry message to measure how much the robot moved.

I couldn't format the code properly using this editor, so I created a post:
http://www.theconstructsim.com/move-certain-distance-turn-move-using-odometry-topic/
But you can see the code below:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose2D.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>

#include <math.h>

geometry_msgs::Pose2D current_pose;
ros::Publisher pub_pose2d;

void odomCallback(const nav_msgs::OdometryConstPtr& msg)
{
    // linear position
    current_pose.x = msg->pose.pose.position.x;
    current_pose.y = msg->pose.pose.position.y;
    
    // quaternion to RPY conversion
    tf::Quaternion q(
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.x,
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.y,
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.z,
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);
    tf::Matrix3x3 m(q);
    double roll, pitch, yaw;
    m.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
    
    // angular position
    current_pose.theta = yaw;
    pub_pose2d.publish(current_pose);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
    
    ROS_INFO("start");
    
    ros::init(argc, argv, "move_pub");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber sub_odometry = n.subscribe("odom", 1, odomCallback);
    ros::Publisher movement_pub = n.advertise("cmd_vel",1); //for sensors the value after , should be higher to get a more accurate result (queued)
    pub_pose2d = n.advertise("turtlebot_pose2d", 1);
    ros::Rate rate(10); //the larger the value, the "smoother" , try value of 1 to see "jerk" movement
    
    //move forward
    ROS_INFO("move forward");
    ros::Time start = ros::Time::now();
    while(ros::ok() && current_pose.x < 1.5)
    {
        geometry_msgs::Twist move;
        //velocity controls
        move.linear.x = 0.2; //speed value m/s
        move.angular.z = 0;
        movement_pub.publish(move);
    
        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }
    //turn right
    ROS_INFO("turn right");
    ros::Time start_turn = ros::Time::now();
    while(ros::ok() && current_pose.theta > -PI/2)
    {
        geometry_msgs::Twist move;
        //velocity controls
        move.linear.x = 0; //speed value m/s
        move.angular.z = -0.3;
        movement_pub.publish(move);
    
        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }
    //move forward again
    ROS_INFO("move forward");
    ros::Time start2 = ros::Time::now();
    while(ros::ok() && current_pose.y > -1.5)
    {
        geometry_msgs::Twist move;
        //velocity controls
        move.linear.x = 0.2; //speed value m/s
        move.angular.z = 0;
        movement_pub.publish(move);
    
        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }
    
    // just stop
    while(ros::ok()) {
        geometry_msgs::Twist move;
        move.linear.x = 0;
        move.angular.z = 0;
        movement_pub.publish(move);
    
        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to reproduce my experiment, you can use the Turtlebot 2 public simulation available in RDS (https://rds.theconstructsim.com/). But you can do it in your own computer too, using this robot.

Basically, you have to consider the current position of the robot to have closed loop. The way it's right now, it relays on time and a very good calibration of the robot, what is not recommended if you want to have a node as generic that could be used in different robots and environments.

Don't forget that you have to add in your CMakeLists.txt and package.xml the dependency **nav_msgs** before trying to compile.

---

Originally posted by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) with karma: 541 on 2017-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
This answer, as it is, limited without the source. Please include the source and information from the post in this answer as links can and do go down/die.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
Also, it is quite easy to format your code in the editor (you've done it in your other answers). Highlight your, code then press the Preformat Text (`101010`) button then your code will be properly formatted.

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2017-08-28**:
Done. I was trying to click on the code button before adding the code itself.
So, the steps are: 1-Add the code, 2-Select it, 3-Code button
Thanks for the tip.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
You can do that too, but from what I've experienced it doesn't work very well for anything longer than very short snippets. It's easier to format the way that you just mentioned.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
Your code is missing the `include`s

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2017-08-28**:
Thanks, fixed! It's awkward, I tried to use "& lt;" and "& gt;" but it didn't work. Then I used "<" and ">" and worked. This problem happens if I copy and paste.